# Python trying to enable application folder/file navigation - import error no module named 'nav'

Tags: python, package, python-import, init

What is a basic solution, or basic alternative solutions, to eliminate  import error no module named 'nav' in the context shown below?

Package (directory) and module (file) structure of application:

```
root\code\
    __init__.py
    nav.py
    resource.txt

root\code\mkts\goog\
    __init__.py
    update_goog.py

root\code\mkts\yhoo\
    __init__.py
    update_yhoo.py

root\mkts\goog\data\
    DJIA.csv

root\mkts\yhoo\data\
    DJIA.csv

root\mkts\goog\human\
    DJIA.txt

root\mkts\yhoo\human\
    DJIA.txt
```

Nav.py (some relevant code)

```
import os

this_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
code = os.path.split(this_path)[0] # DO NOT put os.sep here!
root = os.path.split(code)[0] + os.sep
code = os.path.join(root,'code' + os.sep)

mkts = os.path.join(root,'mkts' + os.sep)

mkts_goog = os.path.join(mkts,'goog' + os.sep)
mkts_goog_data = os.path.join(mkts_goog,'data' + os.sep)
mkts_goog_human = os.path.join(mkts_goog,'human' + os.sep)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # print(test())
```

update_goog.py (relevant import test code)

```
import nav

print(nav.mkts_goog_data)
```

When I run "python update_goog.py" from the command line I expect to see a print of the directory root\mkts\goog\data\ instead Python 3.6 throws the ImportError no module named 'nav'. I have read a bunch of related posts but cannot determine the best basic options for solving my particular problem. I may be missing something simple and don't want to cook up an overly complicated solution.

Answer (score 0):

The module `nav` is several levels above the module `goog` (`nav` is its "grandfather").  As such, you'll need to set up some official packaging structure using Python's methods for doing that.  That will likely involve something like a local `pip install` or a `python setup` or something similar.

Check out [PyPA's Packaging and Distributing Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/).  You can ignore the "distributing" part, but the rest of it will be relevant.

I know I'm really just giving a link, which is a no-no, but the answer is fairly long and involved, and is captured very well in that and similar pages.